# Chapter number not showing on odd pages

Tags: chapters, fancyhdr, roman-numerals

I have set my chapter numbering to Roman, and by using the `fancyhdr` package, I put the chapter number in the top center of each page. However, it is only showing on even numbered pages. Example:

```
\documentclass[12pt, twoside]{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[LO,RE]{TOPIC}
\fancyhead[CE]{Chapter \thechapter}
\fancyhead[CO]{Chapter \thechapter}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[LO]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[RE]{\thepage}
```

Comment: Please augment your code snippet to that it (a) becomes minimally compilable and (b) reproduces the issue you wish to fix. E.g., you mention that "I have set my chapter numbering to Roman"; however, that does not (yet) seem to be reflected in the code. Thanks.

Comment: To expand on the comment by @Mico: when this code is made compilable by adding `\begin{document}`, a chapter with a few pages of content (e.g., using the `lipsum` package) and `\end{document}`, then it actually works as expected, i.e., the chapter number is shown on each page. So please provide a small example document that actually reproduces the error, then it will be much easier to find the solution to your problem.

Comment: You have the page number in the footer:  `\fancyfoot[LO]{\thepage}`